# Как заполнить объект <select> html данными из json

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-events

Есть страница представления, на которой есть объект  (id="StreetId").

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken"
           name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="CityId" asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CityId"></select>
            </di>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="StreetId" asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GetStreets"></select>
            </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Данный объект после изменения объекта с id="CityId" должен обновиться новыми данными пришедшими с сервера в формате json, для чего была написана функция:

```
$(function () {
    $("#CityId").change(function () {
        var formData = { 'CityId': Number.parseInt($('#CityId').val()), 'NameCity': ''};
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:18246/api/streetsAPI/searchStreets",
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function (data) {

                var streets = $('#StreetId');
                streets.empty();

                $.each(data, function (index, street) {
                    //streets.append($('<option/>',
                    //    {
                    //        value: street.IdStreet,
                    //        text: street.Name
                    //    }));
                    $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo(streets); 
                });
            //    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //        $streets.append('<option value = ' + data[i].IdStreet + '>' + data[i].Name + '</option>');
            //    }
            },
            error: function (result, status, er) {
                alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Функция срабатывает, данные в json приходят, но объект  ими почему-то не заполняется.
Пробовал 3 варианта заполнения:
1)

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $streets.append('<option value = ' + data[i].IdStreet + '>' + data[i].Name + '</option>');
                    }
```

2. 

```
$.each(data, function (index, street) {
                            
                            $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo(streets); 
                        });
```

3. 

```
$.each(data, function (index, street) {
                            streets.append($('<option/>',
                                {
                                    value: street.IdStreet,
                                    text: street.Name
                                }));
                        });
```

Но не один не отработал как нужно -  был либо пустой, подозреваю, что не прописалось значение представления (text), либо undefind.

Почему так и как здесь правильней будет заполнить?

Ошибка при попытке взятия значения свойства text объекта select:

> Create:270 Uncaught TypeError: "#StreetId>option".get is not a
> function
> at HTMLSelectElement. (Create:270)
> at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (VM17 jquery.min.js:2)
> at HTMLSelectElement.v.handle (VM17 jquery.min.js:2) (anonymous) @ Create:270 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2 v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Покажите структуру вашего ответа и версию jQuery.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, спасибо! Сейчас когда внимательно посмотрел на ответ json, то увидел, что при конвертации объекта C# в json регистр имен свойств заглавной буквы меняется с верхнего на нижний ) Поэтому у меня и были пустые строки

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, если получится оформите до ответа - поставлю галочку

Comment: Спасибо, но на ответ это ну никак не тянет :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а можете подсказать, как в JS извлечь из select text, когда пытаюсь так "$('#CityId').text()", то он мне возвращает строку со всеми значениями, а не с выделенным

Comment: У `select` надо использовать `val()`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, это так я получаю значение свойства "value", а у меня есть ещё text, которое не совпадает с ним: "<select value="1">text</select>"

Comment: Что-то вроде такого `('#StreetId>option').get($('#StreetId').prop('selectedIndex')).textContent`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, так он не может найти объект '#StreetId>option', а если меняю на '#StreetId', то он не находит метода - "#StreetId".get is not a function

Comment: Какая версия jQuery у вас? Вы уверены, что правильно скопировали мой код?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, jQuery v3.5.1

Comment: Покажите ошибку в вопросе, когда вы используете мой код.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, дополнил вопрос ошибкой при использовании вашего кода

Comment: `$('#StreetId>option:selected').text()`

Comment: @Igor, спасибо - так работает